# Multiple backgrounds & :valid - shortest solution / DRY solution?

Tags: html, css, validation

I have a form with some input-fields. These input fields have a gradient as background assigned, like so:

```
input {
    background: #00b7ea;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%, #009ec3 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#00b7ea), color-stop(100%,#009ec3));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b7ea', endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Now, when the field is validated as `:valid`, I want to add a symbol indicating that everything is ok.  Normally I would try to use the pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after` for that, but not in this case. `:before` and `:after` are rendered inside the element and because an input-field is not allowed to contain any other elements, I couldn't find a way to position them properly.
So I have to display the indicator as background-image, which results in that code:

```
input {
    background: #00b7ea;
    background: url(../images/ok.png), url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: url(../images/ok.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%, #009ec3 100%);
    background: url(../images/ok.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#00b7ea), color-stop(100%,#009ec3));
    background: url(../images/ok.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%);
    background: url(../images/ok.png), -o-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%);
    background: url(../images/ok.png), -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b7ea', endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Now, albeit this solution is working, I repeat the code for the background so that solution is not very DRY.  Can you imagine any other good solution for that problem? Is there any best practice I don't know?

Comment: have you tried using a selector like input:valid + p{}  to select a <p> element after the validation? or would that not work?

Comment: @lukeocom Yes that would work but I am not sure if its a step forward. Because using that technique, I have to create empty paragraphs after every input field which is not very semantic. Also, I wasn't able to position the paragraph correctly - at the moment it is displayed below the input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the aditional image (ok.png) not as a background image but as a border image

```
input:valid {
    border-image: url(../images/ok.png);
}
```

Not sure about older browser support, though